# Difference in js object instances

Tags: javascript

I am new to this kind of stuff, i gone through several tutorials of js and i found this two type of coding standards of functions, shown below :

```
 return({
           error: function(message){
                     // Code here
            },
           debug: function(message){
                     // Code here
           }
       });
```

And another one like

```
 this.error = function(message){
    //Code Here

    };
    this.debug = function(message){
    //Code Here

    };
return this;
```

I am new in coding, so have a little idea about coding formats. Can you please explain a basic difference between above two snippets ?, but the usage of both are same .

Comment: They both assign `error` and `debug` properties, but one creates a new object for them via `{...}` while the other modifies an existing object via `this`. What effect that difference has depends on the surrounding context and value of `this`. Can you expand on your snippets?

Comment: They both don't use prototype, maybe it's time to read different tutorials: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Comment: Could you show how those snippets are called?

Comment: Not much difference in your two simple examples, but using the `new` operator and the prototype chain (which would be more compatible with the second option) enables things like more efficient method storage, easier inheritance, using `instanceof` to identify object types, having a public constructor function, etc...

Answer (score 1):

They are pretty much the same.

The first returns an object literal from a function:

```
 app.factory('myFactory', function() {
    var var1 = 'a';
    var var2 = 'b';
    return  {
         method1: function() { ... },
         method2: function() { ... },
         property1: var1,
         property2: var2
    };
 });
```

The second returns a function that Angular will call like this: var fn = new MyFunction(); This is basically what a service is.

```
app.service('MyFunction', function() {
     var var1 = 'a';
     var var2 = 'b';
     this.method1 = function() { ... };
     this.method2 = function() { ... };
     this.property1 = var1;
     this.property2 = var2;
});
```

Services make use of the 'this' keyword because the function constructor is called (new MyFunction()).

Both are singletons, and both are injectable. As you can see there is little difference between the two.

Comment: Is any use ever made of the *prototype* chain available in the second case? Just curious, I'm not an Angularjs user.

Comment: I would think yes, although, i'm not a big fan of prototype, or knowledgable in it either

Comment: RobG wasn't talking about the library called prototype, rather the prototype chain as it naturally occurs in JavaScript.

Comment: I'm unsure about that

Comment: @pixelbits—ok, so elsewhere you'd declare or initialise *MyFunction* and setup the *MyFunction.prototype* methods, then do `app.service('MyFunction', MyFunction)`, i.e. use a function reference instead of a function epxression.

Comment: Once MyFunction is setup (like I have above), you could inject it into your controller function.  app.controller('MyController', function($scope, MyFunction) {  MyFunction.method1(); });

Answer (score 0):

Those are two different ways of implementing constructors in JavaScript. The difference is how you call the constructor.

In case of

```
function Foo(){
  return { bar : 1 } ;
} ;
```

you call create a new instance of the object by calling it as Foo() or new Foo() or X.Foo(). The constructor property will be however Object constructor.

But in case of

```
function Foo(){
  this.bar = 1 ;
  return this ;
} ;
```

it will return an object with constructor Foo when call it as new Foo(), it will return the global object when call it Foo() and you will have bar=1 in the global object, and it will return X when call it as X.Foo() if X has method Foo, and X will have bar=1 property